# Is the number of basis functions same in the different atoms in the 6-31G basis set?

Tags: gaussian, basis-sets, orbitals

I'm now studying the quantum chemistry calculation and Gaussian basis set.

For example, when using the 6-31G basis set,
the C atom has 6 basis functions in 1s orbital:

- 3+1=4 in $2s$,
- 3+1=4 in $2p_x$,
- 3+1=4 in $2p_y$, and
- 3+1=4 in $2p_z$,

whereas the O atom also has 6 basis functions in 1s orbital:

- 3+1=4 in $2s$,
- 3+1=4 in $2p_x$,
- 3+1=4 in $2p_y$,
- 3+1=4 in $2p_z$.

That is, the number of basis functions is the same in these two atoms, is it correct?

I think that the O atom has more electrons than the C atom, so the number of basis functions should be different and the O atom should have more basis functions than the C atom, but is this my misunderstanding?

Comment: +1. Typically the number of basis functions is the same within a row (so C and O will have the same number of basis functions as Ne, but not as many as Ar).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you're absolutely correct that the basis sets for O and C will typically have the same number of orbitals (not just for the 6-31G basis set but also for the famous cc-pVXZ family, and other basis sets).

It's true that O has more electrons than C, but in both cases, the electrons are primarily occupied in the $1s$, $2s$, and $2p$ orbitals. If you're considering to trim down the carbon basis set to have only $2p_x$ and $2p_y$ (i.e. to remove $2p_z$) things can get imbalanced.

B, C, N, O, F, and Ne will typically all have the same number of basis functions for a given basis set label (such as cc-pVDZ), whereas the corresponding atoms in the next row: Al, Si, P, S, Cl, and Ar will have a slightly bigger basis set than the previous atoms, but they will all have the same number of basis functions as each other.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I found that the number of basis functions is the same even if the number of electrons is different as long as the row is the same.

Answer (score 7):

I think that it is a feature of how the basis set is defined. 6-31G is a valence double-zeta basis set of the Pople family. Here, 6 means that the core orbitals are represented with 6 Gaussian functions (GTO) while 31 means the valence orbitals are split into two orbitals with the scheme 3 GTO + 1 GTO. So, I looked at the basis set data for 6-31G, and it seems to be clear how the orbitals are assigned.

For example, look at the basis sets of N, P and As (group 15):

```
NITROGEN
S   6
1         0.4173511460E+04       0.1834772160E-02
2         0.6274579110E+03       0.1399462700E-01
3         0.1429020930E+03       0.6858655181E-01
4         0.4023432930E+02       0.2322408730E+00
5         0.1282021290E+02       0.4690699481E+00
6         0.4390437010E+01       0.3604551991E+00
L   3
1         0.1162636186E+02      -0.1149611817E+00       0.6757974388E-01
2         0.2716279807E+01      -0.1691174786E+00       0.3239072959E+00
3         0.7722183966E+00       0.1145851947E+01       0.7408951398E+00
L   1
1         0.2120314975E+00       0.1000000000E+01       0.1000000000E+01
```

For nitrogen $\ce{1s->6 GTO; 2s,2p->3GTO + 1GTO}$. A feature of the Pople style basis sets is that the s and p orbitals are fused when possible into an SP orbital (also called "L" orbital). This means that the s and p GTO's from the same orbital have the same exponent, but different coefficients. This was done to reduce the cost of calculations.

```
PHOSPHORUS
S   6
1         0.1941330000E+05       0.1851598923E-02
2         0.2909420000E+04       0.1420619174E-01
3         0.6613640000E+03       0.6999945928E-01
4         0.1857590000E+03       0.2400788603E+00
5         0.5919430000E+02       0.4847617180E+00
6         0.2003100000E+02       0.3351998050E+00
L   6
1         0.3394780000E+03      -0.2782170105E-02       0.4564616191E-02
2         0.8101010000E+02      -0.3604990135E-01       0.3369357188E-01
3         0.2587800000E+02      -0.1166310044E+00       0.1397548834E+00
4         0.9452210000E+01       0.9683280364E-01       0.3393617168E+00
5         0.3665660000E+01       0.6144180231E+00       0.4509206237E+00
6         0.1467460000E+01       0.4037980152E+00       0.2385858009E+00
L   3
1         0.2156230000E+01      -0.2529241139E+00      -0.1776531273E-01
2         0.7489970000E+00       0.3285184468E-01       0.2740581964E+00
3         0.2831450000E+00       0.1081254762E+01       0.7854215630E+00
L   1
1         0.9983170000E-01       0.1000000000E+01       0.1000000000E+01
```

For phosphorus, $\ce{1s->6 GTO; 2s,2p->6 GTO; 3s,3p->3 GTO + 1 GTO}$

```
S   6
1         0.1005955000E+06       0.1726750000E-02
2         0.1510482000E+05       0.1323462000E-01
3         0.3440884000E+04       0.6535848000E-01
4         0.9703961000E+03       0.2278042000E+00
5         0.3112852000E+03       0.4774525000E+00
6         0.1066284000E+03       0.3567619000E+00
L   6
1         0.2166679000E+04       0.2271761000E-02       0.3832156000E-02
2         0.5165414000E+03       0.3033475000E-01       0.3023558000E-01
3         0.1678674000E+03       0.1259057000E+00       0.1328632000E+00
4         0.6364638000E+02      -0.6687172000E-02       0.3447648000E+00
5         0.2613673000E+02      -0.6065306000E+00       0.4640368000E+00
6         0.1085439000E+02      -0.4823144000E+00       0.2064824000E+00
L   6
1         0.9506989000E+02      -0.5587423000E-02      -0.6816583000E-02
2         0.3318087000E+02       0.5632506000E-01      -0.2970303000E-01
3         0.1406773000E+02       0.2625835000E+00       0.4704335000E-01
4         0.6153288000E+01      -0.1718349000E+00       0.3645042000E+00
5         0.2721712000E+01      -0.7175645000E+00       0.4945157000E+00
6         0.1185334000E+01      -0.3184598000E+00       0.2149830000E+00
L   3
1         0.1615315000E+01       0.2645372000E+00      -0.2574061000E-01
2         0.5513300000E+00      -0.1952737000E+00       0.3072764000E+00
3         0.2227620000E+00      -0.9595400000E+00       0.7537368000E+00
L   1
1         0.8292300000E-01       0.1000000000E+01       0.1000000000E+01
D   3
1         0.5030227000E+02       0.8144711000E-01
2         0.1384166000E+02       0.3792908000E+00
3         0.4393458000E+01       0.7040401000E+00
D   1
1         0.1310755000E+01       1.0000000
```

For arsenic, I believe the assignment is:
$\ce{1s->6 GTO; 2s,2p->6 GTO; 3s,3p->6 GTO; 4s,4p-> 3 GTO +1 GTO; 3d-> 3 GTO + 1 GTO}$

The same number of orbitals and GTOs are used in the same row. For example, if you look at the 6-31G basis set for [silicon](https://www.basissetexchange.org/basis/6-31g/format/gamess_us/?version=1&elements=14), you would see the same type of assignment as in phosphorus. This type of scheme seems to be consistent in other basis set families too, as mentioned in @NikeDattani's answer.

[All basis sets are from Basis Set Exchange: https://www.basissetexchange.org/, and in GAMESS(US) format]

Comment: Thanks for your answer and very detailed examples! It will be very helpful for my study.